# Поиск строк по ключевой фразе в Python

Tags: python, строки, find

Есть .txt лог файл с большим количеством строк. Необходимо построить условие которое позволит найти строки содержащие фразы 'Start execution of step' или 'End of execution of step' и записать эти строки полностью в новый текстовый файл.

```
from os 
import getcwd 

file = open('Ref_Log.txt', 'r') 
data = file.read() 
print(data) # тут я вижу все строки 
clear_file = [] 

with open('Ref_Log.txt', 'r') as file_input: 
    for l in file_input: 
        if not l.contains('Start execution of step' or 'End of execution of step'): #получаю ошибку 'str' object has no attribute 'contains' clean_list.append(1) 

with open('Ref_Log.txt', 'w') as file_output: 
    file_output.write('\n'.join(clean_list))
```

Comment: это русская версия stackoverflow поэтому вопросы долны быть на русском

Comment: спасибо, все исправил

Comment: в чем именно у вас возникла проблема? С построчным чтением файла? или с поиском подстроки в строке?

Comment: Покажите ваш код, если он есть. Если нет - тогда идите и попробуйте написать

Comment: и с чтением построчно, и с поиском подстроки
Месяц как начал изучать пайтон, опыта практически нет

Comment: from os import getcwd
file = open('Ref_Log.txt', 'r')
data = file.read()
print(data)  # тут я вижу все строки 

clear_file = []
with open('Ref_Log.txt', 'r') as file_input:
    for l in file_input:
          if not l.contains('Start execution of step' or 'End of execution of step'):  #получаю ошибку 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
            clean_list.append(1)

with open('Ref_Log.txt', 'w') as file_output:
          file_output.write('\n'.join(clean_list))

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('log.txt') as f:
    for i in f.readlines():
        if 'Start execution of step' in i or 'End of execution of step'in i:
            with open('log2.txt', 'a') as f2:
                f2.write(i)
```

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)